# Why is my [:Rating] attribute nil when my other attributes have values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes, null

I'm trying to set up a rating system. I recently upgraded my migrations file.

```
class AddRatingsToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pictures, :ratings_count, :integer
    add_column :pictures, :rating_total, :integer
    add_column :pictures, :rating, :integer
  end
end
```

Here is my code in my model

```
def ratings_count
  self[:ratings_count] || 0
end

def ratings_total
  self[:rating_total] || 0
end

def add_rating(rating)
  return if rating.nil? || rating == 0

  self.ratings_count += 1
  self.rating_total += rating.to_i
  self.stars = (self.rating_total.to_f / self.ratings_count)
  self.save
end

def rating
  self[:rating] || 0
  return 0 if self.ratings_count == 0
  (self.rating_total.to_f / self.ratings_count).round(2)
end
```

Here are some things I tried in Rails Console

```
p = Picture.find(1)
p.rating == nil
false
p[:rating] == nil
true
```

I think the problem lies in this snippet.

```
def rating
  self[:rating] || 0
  return 0 if self.ratings_count == 0
  (self.rating_total.to_f / self.ratings_count).round(2)
end
```

If I call *.rating* on an object it returns the correct rating. If I call [:rating] on an object it returns nil.

The reason I ask this is because I need this for Active Record Querying, where I have to call the actual attribute. Specifically, this line of code.

```
<% Picture.where("rating >= 4.5").order(rating: :desc, title: :asc).each do |picture|  %>
```

My rating method works, but only as a method call, not as an attribute. And considering that :ratings_count and :rating_total both work.

```
p.ratings_count
=> 2
p[:ratings_count]
=> 2
p.rating_total
=> 9
p[:rating_total]
=> 9
```

So it seems my methods work for creating attributes for my model. The reason is probably in my add_rating method.

```
def add_rating(rating)
  return if rating.nil? || rating == 0

  self.ratings_count += 1
  self.rating_total += rating.to_i
  self.stars = (self.rating_total.to_f / self.ratings_count)
  self.save
end
```

Above, I called the save method, which probably recorded the attribute in the model.

I think I'm pretty close but it looks like I need help. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the problem. It was that I was storing rating as an integer and not as a decimal.

```
add_column :pictures, :rating, :integer, default: 0, null: false
```

should have been

```
add_column :pictures, :rating, :decimal, default: 0, null: false
```

My method required me to divide rating_total an integer by ratings_count. I used type conversion to convert the number to decimal but the value itself was stored as an integer.

Changing the migration solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve the `add_rating` tripping things up, but you can setup defaults in your migration so they are never nil and you can simplify the logic going on for each method, might make it easier to track down the problem.

```
class AddRatingsToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pictures, :ratings_count, :integer, default: 0
    add_column :pictures, :rating_total, :integer, default: 0
    add_column :pictures, :rating, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think that's the answer. My ratings_count and rating_total attributes weren't nil, and I didn't include default: 0. It might be worth taking a look at though.

Answer (score 1):

`picture[:rating]` returns the actual attribute value of the column as it is in the database, so if the value in the database is not set, it will return `nil`, even though you've set the type to integer in your migration.

In your code, there's a lot of conditionals like `self[:rating] || 0` and `if rating.nil? || rating == 0`. This is getting complicated, since you're expecting either `nil` OR `0`. The easiest way to overcome this complexity is to tell the database to not allow null values, and set some default (in your case 0). You should make a migration like this:

```
class AddRatingsToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pictures, :ratings_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
    add_column :pictures, :rating_total, :integer, null: false, default: 0
    add_column :pictures, :rating, :integer, null: false, default: 0
  end
end
```

Now, your database ensures you will *never* have null values in those columns, and it takes care of setting the default value in case you don't provide one.

Now you can reduce your code as well:

```
def add_rating(rating)
  return if rating.to_i == 0

  self.ratings_count += 1
  self.rating_total += rating.to_i
  self.stars = (rating_total.to_f / ratings_count)
  self.save
end

def rating
  return 0 if ratings_count == 0

  (rating_total.to_f / ratings_count).round(2)
end
```

Now, looking at the code, you're setting some attribute `stars` as the average rating. The actual `rating` attribute is not set at all. There's not enough information for me to be sure, but I'm assuming `stars` should actually be `rating` here? So then you get:

```
def add_rating(rating)
  return if rating.to_i == 0

  self.ratings_count += 1
  self.rating_total += rating.to_i
  self.rating = (rating_total.to_f / ratings_count)
  self.save
end
```

Comment: This has potential, unfortunately this line is a problem. self.rating_total += rating.     This results in a TypeError: String can't be coerced into fixnum. I understand we set the type to integer, but maybe we needed to convert rating_total to a float first. I'll look into this. We also removed the rating_total and ratings_count methods.

Comment: I guess the argument would be a string then. I updated my answer to cast it to an integer. You already had this casting in place, I guess I was a bit too eager to remove it ;)

Comment: Perfect, this fixed my problem with nil. But [:rating] is still set to 0 and not the calculated rating.